# convert list to grid view and vice versa in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I have a list view, I would like to change my list view to grid view when user click on a button. like below images :

grid view:

[image]

list view :

[image]

Comment: Please show code and what you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for list

```
gridview.setNumColumns(1);
```

and for grid

```
gridview.setNumColumns(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

in the same layout keep both `ListView` and `GridView`, and change their visibility accordingly to the button. If you have to show the `ListView` you hide the `GridView` and the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Another Simple Solution would be...

While clicking the button make the Grid View Column count = 1
and when you want Grid View make column count= 2